# Regex match all whitespace sepearated tokens that are in a specific pattern

Tags: regex

For example text

```
Lorem Ipsum is. simply-dummy text/of 
the printing and'typesetting  industry
```

I'd like to all the token separated by whitespace characters `\s` that is in `[a-zA-Z]`
So the matches will be

```
Lorem
Ipsum
the
printing
industry
```

I know I can first split and then match every token using `[a-zA-Z]`, but I'd like to know whether it's possible to use only 1 regular expression to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assert whitespace boundaries to the left and right using negative lookarounds asserting not a non whitespace char.

```
(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Uefrd/1)

Answer (score 0):

This one should do it:

```
(?<=\s|^)([A-Za-z]+)(?=\s|$)
```

Example on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/W9Us6t/1).

Comment: Is it possible without the outermost pair of parenthesis ?  Currently there are 2 groups matched per string match. i.e. Group1 and Group2 for each Match

Comment: @SeaBean Yeah, I was testing something else before so they stuck :) Thanks for the heads up, edited :)

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the quick reply. I'm using python, when I input your result `re.compile(r"(?<=\s|^)([A-Za-z]+)(?=\s|$)")` it says  `re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern` on `\s|^`